# App services with Active Directory Authentication enabled is not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

[image: Log in with AAD]
[image: Error]
[image: Redirect URLs]
[image: New error after add URI]

I have an App Service created following **active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2-master/1-WebApp-OIDC** example. App registration it's ok. Code it's ok. Web App is working as expected, if I'm not signed in, I'm redirected to my Authentication Provider (in this case Microsoft). After login successfully with my provider, provider sends a valid token to my web site and my web site let me access it. Additionally, in the same browser, single sign-on its working properly.

But my organization policies requires that I change the value "allow anonymous requests (no action" to "Log in with Azure Active Directory" on "Authentication / Authorization" under App Service section. I setup Azure Active Directory as "Configured (Express: Existing App)".
After this change, always I get the same Error when accessing my Web Site:

"AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'a29a8677-6c93-4b9e-9c9f-b7d86b17be1d'."

¿Enabling authentication using the portal may not be supported with .Net Core 3.1 and MSAL?

From now, that I added the correct URI, I have a new error:
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means your redirect url is not correct, navigate to the App Registration you configured for your web app in the portal -> `Authentication`, add a redirect url
with the format as `https://webappname.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`.

[image]

If it still not work, just select the `Create New AD App` instead of `Select Existing AD app` in this [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings), it will do all the configurations automatically for you, then it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks Joy, I missed "/callback" on my Redirect URIs, but now I'm getting this error: You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Comment: @EMP Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Enterprise applications` -> search for the name of your AD App(select `Application Type` with `All Applications`  ) -> click your App -> `Properties`, see if the  `User assignment required` is `Yes`. If it is `Yes`, you need to add your user account to the `Users and groups`, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-assign-users#assign-users-to-an-app). You can also turn it to `No`, then you will not need to add the user to the app.

Comment: I found that "User assigment required is No" in my case, so I think this is not the problem. I think the problem is related to the use in conjunction of a Middleware authentication on my code, because I'm redirected to /signin-oidc

Comment: @EMP To use the `Authentication / Authorization` of the web app, no need to configure any authentication in your code, the feature is above the code. If it still not work, try to  select the `Create New AD App` as I mentioned in my reply.

Comment: This is the root problem: I need someone to confirm that using the Authentication / Authorization in the azure portal has an incompatibility with an additional authentication in code, and If I need authentication by code (thats my case) I can't active this on azure portal to work. But, under this situation, I need a way to specify that I'm using code authentication. I think Mircrosoft could solve my problem adding additional option on "Action to take when request is not authenticated": "Login with Azure Active Directory by Middleware (by code)" and by this way allowing me to be compliant.